# Azure Yaml pipelines : How to reset a parameter after running the pipeline before "Run new"

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm using parameters within my yaml pipeline which are set on runtime by the user.
For example:

```
parameters:
  - name: StartAfterDeployment
    displayName: 'Start after deployment'
    type: boolean
    default: true
```

When the pipeline has ran successfully and (and the user selected false), and the user choose "Run new" on that deployment. The option is selected false instead of the default true.

Is it possible to "reset" the parameters to the default settings when choosing the Run new option or to disable completely the run rew option?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to "reset" the parameters to the default settings when choosing the Run new option or to disable completely the run rew option?

I am afraid there is no such way to konw the value of the run rew option.

We have to manually select the value when we rerun the pipeline, we could change the YAML like:

```
parameters:
  - name: StartAfterDeployment
    displayName: 'Start after deployment'
    type: string
    values:
      - true
      - false
    default: true
```

[image]

Comment: This is not solving the problem. 
The default value works only when running a pipeline.
Once a pipeline has ran and choose run new. It chooses th selected option